# I can't add data to the database using a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

If I leave everything as it is, then an error pops up when submitting the form

> "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available
> choices."

And, for example, if in **forms.py** I change `Product.objects.values_list('product_name')` to a class with one field, for example, `Category.objects.all()`, the form is submitted without errors
But I need exactly the first option, where I select a specific class field (`product_name`), so that there are the necessary options in the form in the select...
Who knows how to solve this problem?

models.py:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    uploader_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    geo = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    product_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/logos', blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name, self.description, self.geo,


class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

forms.py:

```
class AddForm(forms.Form):
    uploader_mail = forms.EmailField(
        label='Owner mail',
        initial='test@test.test',
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    body = forms.CharField(
        label='Data line by line',
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control','wrap': "off", }))
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Product.objects.values_list('product_name', flat=True),
        label='Category',
        empty_label=None,
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select'}))
```

views.py:

```
def edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data)
    else:
        form = AddForm()
    editable = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'goods_list/edit.html', editable)
```

Comment: change your  __str__ method of Product model like this `return self.product_name`